# Confidence interval for a rate where there is uncertainty around the exposure (number of days)

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, uncertainty

We'd like to test if two rates (number of occurrences / number of days) are statistically different for a paper. However, for one of the rates (let's say Rate A), we have uncertainty around the exposure (number of days).

We have several different estimates for the exposure of Rate A. But the exposure variability is not statistically modeled.

We'd like to test the statistical difference between Rate A and the other rate, ideally where the  confidence interval for Rate A can capture the uncertainty we have around the exposure estimates.

We have a few ideas that would be great to get some thoughts on:

- Don't account for uncertainty in Rate A's exposure estimates. Choose one exposure estimate and then use Poisson distribution
- Estimate an upper and lower bound for Rate A (without using a proper statistical method) and say this is our confidence interval. I don't know if this is kosher, especially if we'd like to publish. But could this be a reasonable approach to make non-statistical statements about the difference between two rates for a paper?

(I'm not a statistician, so apologies for any improper terminology)

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV. What measure of uncertainty do you have on the exposure rates, and how was it derived?

Comment: Hi @AlexJ, thanks! We don't actually have a measure of uncertainty. What we have is a few different estimates of the exposure.

Comment: How were these estimates obtained?

Comment: *"we have several different estimates for the exposure of Rate A"* **1)** what sort of estimates? **2)** what do you mean by the exposure of a rate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a "best way" for this. All your results will have to be taken with a big pinch of salt, given that you are basically guessing the exposure time, and you don't know if your estimates are biased. Some options are:

- Use your own knowledge of how the exposure times were guessed, to choose the best one and go with that. This is the simplest option, but does not account for any uncertainty in the exposure.
- Use inverse variance weights in regression. For each point, find the variance of the exposure estimates, and use the inverse of the variance as a "weight" for each observation. This assumes that on average, any estimate of exposure rate is unbiased. A bit more complicated.
- Run the regression multiple times, once for each estimation method for exposure time. Critically examine the results (not just p-values; check for sense against your expert knowledge). If they are consistent, and that's some support for your hypothesis.
- Apply your method of estimating exposure time, to Rate B (for which you *do* have exact exposure times). Use that to quantify how "good" your exposure estimates are via regression or some other form of analysis. Then, based upon those findings, pick one of the above methods to estimate the relationship between exposure and occurrences.

Note on implications of guessing exposure times:

- If they are randomly centered around zero, it's just adding noise to the estimate. So no bias, but you're less likely to pick up an effect.
- If exposure is over-estimated, then your estimate of Rate A will be too low.
- If exposure is under-estimated, then your estimate of Rate A will be too high.